# Legend Item Spacing in QGIS 3.10

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, legend, formatting

When I use smaller fonts in the legend (anything less than 20pts) there's an awkward gap between the items. I have set all the relevant spacing options in the Legend Properties (i.e. space between symbols, symbol label space, and line space) to 0, but the gap remains. Am I missing something?

[image: legend items with 8pt font]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the symbol height under Symbol, and if that isn't enough, you might wish to consider using a different size for your map layout if your text needs to be that small relative to the size of your features...

Comment: Thanks! Not the exact answer, but it helped me figure out what I was doing wrong. I had made the symbols invisible in the TOC, but their height was still affecting the spacing in the Legend.